# Resize Bootstrap Menu Multi-Column Based on Size of List

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a bootstrap menu list that is dynamically updated based on which user is logged in.

At the smallest list, it would just be 15 items.  At the largest list, it would be 26 items. The list items are added within the view dynamically based on permissions.

The current bootstrap solutions to this is a multi-column layout based on the size of the screen and a static number of items in the list.

Is based on the size of the screen.
https://jsfiddle.net/maciej_p/eatv1b4b/18/

Is based on a static amount of items "This is what I am currently using"
http://alijafarian.com/bootstrap-multi-column-dropdown-menu/

I need a menu list that is created based a dynamic list that is expanded or contracting based on the number of items in the menu.  I could potentially write a menu based upon each permission, but I think that would generate 3 times the amount of code.

I was thinking something like a full list of items below, but I add columns based on list count.  I don't know the amount of items that will be in the list till after it loads.  So I can't turn columns on and off when the list exceeds 20 items.

Please help?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
        <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">click this<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu columns">
            <li><a href="#"><strong>Górny Śląsk</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat będziński</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat bielski</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat bieruńsko-lędziński</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat cieszyński</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat częstochowski</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat gliwicki</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat kłobucki</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat lubliniecki</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat mikołowski</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat myszkowski</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add what you tried

Comment: the first link within the post, the JSFIDDLE link is what I have tried.  Though, it only resizes based on screen size, rather than list size.  If a list is greater than 10 or more items, it should expand out to the second column

Comment: I think you need JavaScript (JQuery)

Comment: that comment doesn't help me...

Comment: Please read this site's FAQs on How To Ask. I doubt someone will write up a JS from scratch for you. We need you to try, and we'll help from there.

Comment: I have 12+ years of developer experience with 2+ years bootstrap and 3,500 stackoverflow creds, of course I have tried....

Comment: If you tried JS, post it. I understand that to be all help I can give here.

Comment: Could you cache the menu items in an array while you loop, get the total count and know how many columns, then build the menu from the array? Or skip the array and loop twice since its max 26 items.

Comment: @SpoiledTechie.com Please, tell me if I'm right. You need dynamic column count change based on menu items in list? If there 10 items = 1 column, if 15 items = 2 column...? My english not so good :)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that.  If I did that, I wouldn't be building the menu in a VIEW anymore, but rather on the backend code.  I would like to keep it within the view if I can.

Comment: @Narek-T thats correct.  But I don't know the amount of items within the list until after its been generated to the view.  Thats why I was hoping for this to be a CSS and bootstrap solution..

Comment: @SpoiledTechie.com ok,  how many items maximum may be in 1 column? Eg if there more than 10 items - become 2 columns

Comment: @Narek-T lets go with 10 items maximum for now.  I can change it if the example doesn't give the best results.

Comment: @SpoiledTechie.com are you looking for something like that? https://jsfiddle.net/eatv1b4b/49/

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use some jQuery. If I understand correctly you want columns count based on `li` count inside `.dropdown-menu`.

You need to check your `li` count after dom load, and based on that do your staff.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var columnCount = $(".columns li").length;
  if (columnCount <= 10) {
    $(".columns").addClass("one-col");
  } else if (columnCount > 10 && columnCount <= 20) {
    $(".columns").addClass("two-col");
  } else if (columnCount > 20) {
    $(".columns").addClass("three-col");
  }
})
```

```css
.columns.one-col {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.columns.two-col {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  column-count: 2;
  width: 500px;
  height: 170px;
}
.columns.three-col {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  column-count: 2;
  width: 500px;
  height: 170px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">

    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">click this<b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu columns">
            <li><a href="#"><strong>Górny Śląsk</strong></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat będziński</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat bielski</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat bieruńsko-lędziński</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat cieszyński</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat częstochowski</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat gliwicki</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat kłobucki</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat lubliniecki</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat mikołowski</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">powiat myszkowski</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </nav>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span style="color:red">&laquo; click on the edge of frame and move it to the left to see how menu changes into two column</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Narek_T/eatv1b4b/52/) link for testing.